# Changing multiple pngs in large project, eg, <img src="map.png"> to <img src="map.svg>" and keeping the css for the images

Tags: css, svg, sass, png

basically im working on a large project which use many icons such as email icon in png format. I've been given some new icons in svg format to replace the png's as well as change the colors of the icons.

I'm new to using svg and the problem is not being able to manipulate color such as .icon{ fill: black; } doesn't work. Is there a way to fill the colors? and is there a way to keep all the current css styling?

Comment: Put the css in the map.svg file itself.

Comment: the project is quite large we talking 30+ icons which already has styling, it will be a long process just changing the png to svg on the asp.net side